# Statistics module doesn't show the "Enable access log" checkbox

Tags: 8, nodes

[Drupal 8 Statistics Configuration http://curiosidad-racional.tk/drupal8statistics.png](http://curiosidad-racional.tk/drupal8statistics.png)

I dont know what to do to show "Enable access log" option.

I activated logging all messages and checked all statistics permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. That's the only thing that statistics.module is doing in 8.x.

Anything else was removed. Maybe there will be or already are contrib modules providing what statistics module did in 7.x. But tools like [Google analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) or [Piwik](https://www.drupal.org/project/piwik) provide a lot better data anyway.